# Errors launching Matlab from bash script... likely silly

Tags: linux, bash, matlab

I have the following bash script, calling the matlab script below:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

var1=HelloWorld
var2=1:4

matlab -nosplash -nodisplay -r "testtest('$var1', $var2), exit"
```

and

```
function testtest(in1, in2)
if ischar(in2)
  in2 = str2num(in2)
end

in1
total = sum(in2)

return
```

I get the following errors (seems to be independent of the function I try to call):

```
+ var1=HelloWorld
+ var2=1:4
+ matlab -nosplash -nodisplay -r 'testtest('\''HelloWorld'\'', 1:4), exit'
MATLAB_MOD_VERSION:
MATLAB_VERSION: R2014a
LM_LICENSE_FILE (before Matlab is loaded) :
LM_LICENSE_FILE (after Matlab is loaded) : #@#
**************************************************************

... Matlab load text ...

**************************************************************
Executing: /app/matlab/R2014a/bin/matlab -nosplash -nodisplay -r testtest('HelloWorld', 1:4), exit
/app/matlab/R2014a/bin/matlab -c #@# -nosplash -nodisplay -r testtest('HelloWorld', 1:4), exit
/app/matlab/R2014a/bin/matlab: eval: line 1682: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
/app/matlab/R2014a/bin/matlab: eval: line 1682: `exec  "/work1/app/matlab/R2014a-gcc/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB"  -c #@# -nosplash -nodisplay -r "testtest('HelloWorld'," 1:4), exit'
/app/matlab/R2014a/bin/matlab: line 1682: warning: syntax errors in . or eval will cause future versions of the shell to abort as Posix requires
```

(Note, I replaced the license number with #@#, above)
Thoughts?

Edit: It appears to not like the spaces within the double quotes. If I get rid of the spaces, it works, but I want to say that there is a way to make this work with spaces... I guess not critical to me though. I think it has to do with my single/double quote usage. I've searched around, and as far as I can tell, I'm doing things right...

Comment: I was not able to recreate your error on Matlab R2014a, Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: If you look into the second to last line of the output it seems the apostrophes are at the wrong places in the error. Could you echo the command string in the bash file just to make sure?

Answer (score 0):

I also thought the quotes were off after looking at the echos.

After more digging, I found that modules are setup for the c-shell, and they are not configured by default for bash. Although I thought Matlab was loaded, this was not the case. I had to manually source the modules for bash, and from there, the code above worked fine.

The code to source and load the module was:

```
. /etc/profile.d/modules.sh
modules load matlab/R#####
```

Where ##### was the matlab version. That will be system-dependent as I understand things.

Primary reference:
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/script-executing-problem-module-command-not-found-761592/

Thanks for your help. I am new to the community... I have found many answers to past questions here!